# Ternary in jsx to add selected attribute to option

Tags: reactjs

I am using the following code to add selected to an option:

```
 <select name="hourSelect" ref="hourSelect">
           {hourSelect.map((option) => (
                  <option value={option.value} {(selectedHour == option.value) ? 'selected' : ''}>{option.label} </option>
            ))}
        </select>
```

I getting the syntax error:
Syntax error: C:/sites/CalendarRedux/src/components/modals/AddAchievementModal.js: Unexpected token, expected ... (94:52)

```
  92 |             <select name="hourSelect" ref="hourSelect">
  93 |                {hourSelect.map((option) => (
> 94 |                       <option value={option.value} {(selectedHour == option.value) ? 'selected' : ''}>{option.label} </option>
     |                                                     ^
  95 |                 ))}
  96 |             </select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign the value true or false to `selected` property (missed the property name), like this:

```
<option value={option.value} selected = {selectedHour == option.value ? true : false}>{option.label} </option>
```

I will suggest you to use the [controlled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) by using the value property of `select` and maintain that value by `state` variable.

Check the working snippet:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
    }

    render(){
       return(
           <select onChange={e => {}}>
              <option value='1' disabled>Select</option>
              {
                  [2,3,4].map((i,j)=>{
                      return <option selected={i == 2 ? true : false} key={i} value={i}>{i}</option>
                  })
              }
           </select>
       );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You skip the attribute name or have specified multiple value try this:

```js
 <select name="hourSelect" ref="hourSelect">
   {hourSelect.map((option) => (
     <option value={option.value} selected={
         (selectedHour == option.value) ? 'selected' : ''
       }
      >{option.label} </option>
    ))}
  </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `selected=` before the property value.

```
<select name="hourSelect" ref="hourSelect">
    {hourSelect.map((option) => (
        <option value={option.value} selected={(selectedHour == option.value) ? 'selected' : ''}>{option.label} </option>
    ))}
</select>
```

(As a side note, if `selected` is expecting a `boolean` value, you could change it to `selected={selectedHour == option.value}`.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's like that

```
selected={(city.city_id == person.city_id) ? 'selected' : ''}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Answers with only code tend to get flagged by the community as "low quality" and deleted.  Please take a look in the help section of the site and read about what makes a good Answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering

Answer (score 0):

First option will show your previous selected option.

Loop option will show all list and hide selected option.

```
<select name="city" value={this.state.city} onChange={this.handleChange}>
    <option value={this.state.getUserData?.user_data?.city?.id}> 
       {this.state.getUserData?.user_data?.city?.value}</option>
         {this.state.city_list.map(rolls1 => {
            return ( <option style={{display:this.state.getUserData?.user_data?.city?.id == rolls1.id ? 'none' : ''}} key={rolls1.id} value={rolls1.id}>{rolls1.name}</option>
            )}  
       )};
 </select>
```